# load ajax page on onload?

Tags: ajax

In my index.html page I want to load a seperate ajax page when the app is loading, 
what is the best way of doing that? 
This is my index code:

loading ajax subpage here.....

And the subpage is just:

content..............

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using JavaScript you can do that. You have to do that on page load. Here is an example in jQuery.

```
$(function(){
    $('#content').load('/content.html');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Teja, I will test it. 
So in my index page I have to have a div with id="content" for the above to work!?

Comment: Im trying this, but its not working, what Im I missing?:
$(function(whenload){
    $('#hem').load('home/home1.asp');
});

<body onLoad="whenload();">

and my home1.asp is looking like this:
<div id="hem2">

  asp content here

</div>

Comment: I dont remember who to get the code with the grey background here :-)
I thought it was just wrapping it with <code></code>?

Comment: you can just copy my code block and try changing the id and URL. your function signature is wrong. `$(function(){....})` signature in jQuery means to load it on page load, so you don't need to name it like you are doing wrong and you don't need to call it on load. Also you sure did included jQuery.js? if possible post the code in jsbin

Answer (score 0):

As an example, you can call a javascript function when the body of your main page loads using the `onload` property of `body`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body onload="loadContent();">
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Among your javascript functions, you will need your `loadContent` function as well as some functions that perform the HTTPRequest-related operations.

```
function loadContent()
{
    var contentURL = "contentpage.xml";
    http.Open("GET", contentURL, true);
    http.onreadystatechange = useHttpResponse;
    http.send(null);
}

var http = getXMLHTTPRequest();
function getXMLHTTPRequest()
{
try
{
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
catch (err1)
{
    try
    {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (err2)
    {
        try
        {
            req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (err3)
        {
            req = false;
        }
    }
}
return req;
}

function useHttpResponse()
{
    if (http.readyState == 4)
    {
        if (http.Status == 200)
        {
             var xml = http.responseXML;
             // do something with loaded XML (such as populate a DIV or something)
        }
    }
}
```

You should check out some [AJAX tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+tutorial) online for more complete information.

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery: [www.jquery.com](http://www.jquery.com)

There are loads of examples and docs on the website, as well as tons of tutorials on the web.

Good luck