# loading a new html file

Tags: html

i am a beginner in html. i would like to do something like this,I am using the below code to create tabs, now i have the contents of the section in a different html file. Please tell me how to load that html file inside the section.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tabs.css">
<body>
    <article class="tabs">
        <section id="tab1">
            <h2><a href="#tab1">NewRecord</a></h2>
            <p>This content appears on tab 1.</p>
        </section>
    </article>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to use javascript/jQuery i advice you this http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @user1878200 this answer your question http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**
Use [iframes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe) to archive this. It will display another page.

**Option 2**
Use `Ajax` [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548094/load-ajax-page-on-onload)

Answer (score 0):

HTML is the **structure**, CSS is the **style** (appearance), and JavaScript is the **behavior**. You can't load data with just structure alone, you'll need to introduce some scripts in there. jQuery is a common library that's fairly easy to learn, but there's many available.

Answer (score 0):

**You can load the content from another HTML file via jQuery '.load()' method.**

Step 1 - Include jQuery in your code.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Step 2 - Add this code before the closing `</body>` tag.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tab1').load('html-file-1.html');    
    });
</script>
```

Step 3 - Your external html file `html-file-1.html` contains nothing but simple html tags to represent the content you want to load within the section.